# Getting vector which holding certain point

Tags: opencv, vector, point

I've a vector of points from a grey section of an image and written like this:

```cpp
std::vector<Point> vectorg;
for(i = 0; i <= hei - 1; i++) {
   for(j = 0; j <= wid - 1; j++) {
      if(mask(i,j) == 128) {
          vectorg.push_back(Point(j,i));
      }
   }
}
```

Knowing what coordinates stored in certain cell is possible by:

```cpp
cout << vectorg[0].x;
cout << vectorg[0].y;
```

The question is now the other way around, is it possible to know which cell holds certain coordinates?
Thanks a lot, I'm new here also with opencv programming, I'll be in your care.

Comment: Do you have several vector's to store coordinates? Or you just want to iterate over the vector to find out a certain (x, y) pair?

Comment: _vectorg_ holds all the coordinates of the grey pixels.
What I wanted to ask is, if it's possible to give the coordinates as input and get as output the cell of vectorg which holds the said coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late response, and thanks for the answers, they inspired me indirectly.

I found an easy way to do it. This is by making another Mat which holds the numbers where the coordinates were saved.

```
std::vector<Point> vectorg;
cv::Mat_<int> Index =Mat_<int>::zeros(hei,wid);
for(i = 0; i <= hei - 1; i++) {
   for(j = 0; j <= wid - 1; j++) {
      if(mask(i,j) == 128) {
          vectorg.push_back(Point(j,i));
          Index(vector[count])=count;
          count++;
      }
   }
}
```

This way I can know which cell holds certain coordinates by simply:

```
cout<<Index(36,362); //as example
```

Thanks a lot, I'll be in your care next time.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
// ...

Point p(searchedX, searchedY);

std::vector<Point>::iterator element = std::find(vectorg.begin(), vectorg.end(), p);

if (element != vectorg.end()) {
    cout << (*element).x << endl;
    cout << (*element).y << endl;
} else {
    cout << "The point is not in the vector" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be overkill, but a way to do it (without doing a greedy exhaustive search) would be to build a [FLANN index](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/flann/doc/flann_fast_approximate_nearest_neighbor_search.html) that will store the position of your points.

The feature matrix is made of the coordinates of your points.
Since OpenCV knows how to convert a vector to a matrix, you should be able to use your current vector as is.
Then, if you want only one point, just ask for the 1 nearest neighbour in the query (k parameter).

The bonus is, if you decide later that you need to have also the closest points in the neighborhood, just raise the value of k.